# Phonegap traçar Rota

Tags: apache-cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocalização

Como faço para traçar uma rota pelo Phonegap e acompanhar o percurso pra que ao final ele me diga qual o meu percurso e quantos km, mts, etc eu percorir?